Unable to Publish DotNET Package to GitHub for One Specific Package Despite Identical Configuration
Hello Stack Overflow Community,
I've encountered a peculiar issue with publishing a .NET package to GitHub Packages and would greatly appreciate any insights or advice. Our team has successfully published numerous .NET packages to GitHub, using a standard workflow and configuration. However, starting last week, we've run into a problem with one specific package that refuses to publish, despite seemingly identical settings and configurations as the ones that work.
Background:
Tooling: We're using GitHub Actions for CI/CD to automate the process of building and publishing .NET packages to GitHub Packages.
Issue: For all our packages, this process has been smooth and without issues. However, one package started failing during the publish step, even though we haven't made any significant changes to the workflow or the package settings.
Error Message: The error we receive is a generic authentication error (or specify the exact error message if available), which doesn't make sense since the authentication token and permissions have not changed and are working fine for other packages.
Steps Taken:
Verified that the GitHub Actions workflow file for the problematic package matches those of the packages that are publishing without issues.
Double-checked the permissions and scopes of the GitHub token used in the CI/CD process to ensure it has write:packages scope.
Compared the repository settings for the problematic package against those of the successfully published packages to spot any discrepancies, but found none.
Looked through the GitHub Actions run logs for any clues or differences in the setup or execution of the workflow for this package compared to others.
Question:
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or does anyone have insights into what might be causing this problem for one specific package? Are there known issues or nuances with GitHub Packages that could lead to a situation where one package fails to publish under identical conditions where others succeed?
I'm looking for any suggestions on troubleshooting steps we might have missed or any configurations specific to GitHub Packages that could cause this behavior.
Thank you in advance for your help!
